# How to use for inside JOptionPane to iterate over array and display a custom message?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am finishing a school project (my first Java course) and I am told to use `JOptionPane` **only.**
I need to do something like this ***but*** using `JOptionPane` and no `System.out.println`:

```
int[] den = {1000, 500, 100 ,50, 20, 10 ,5, 2, 1};
System.out.println("\nDENOMINATIONS: \n");

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    count = amount / den[i]; // counting number of den[i] notes
    if (count != 0) { //printing that denomination if the count is not zero
        System.out.println(den[i] + "\tx\t" + count + "\t= " + den[i] * count);
    }
    totalNotes = totalNotes + count; //finding the total number of notes
    amount = amount%den[i]; //finding the remaining amount 
}
System.out.println("--------------------------------");
System.out.println("TOTAL\t\t\t= " + copy); 
System.out.println("--------------------------------");
System.out.println("Total Number of Notes\t= " + totalNotes);
```

Which prints something beautiful like this:

```
DENOMINATIONS:

1000     x     14     =   14000
500      x     1      =   500
100      x     3      =   300
50       x     1      =   50
5        x     1      =   5
1        x     1      =   1
————————————–
TOTAL                 =   14856
————————————–
Total Number of Notes = 21
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-). You can add any component to the option pane. The "message" parameter can be a simple String to display text, or it can be a Swing Component or it can be an Array containing Strings and components, in which case multiple components will be added to the option pane vertically.

So you could add your text to a JTextArea. Then add the text area to the option pane.

You will also want to change the Font of the text area to a monospaced font so that you can align the text properly.